# Using netplan with ucarp

Tags: netplan

we know that new version of the Ubuntu fully support the Netplan. So I want to ask how can I use this feature with ucarp protocol (application). How can i integrate the Netplan with ucarp.If there isn't any solution, what are the alternative ways to use this feature.
Thanks for your attention.i'm looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 5):

Its possible to make UCARP work with Netplan:

At first you should edit /usr/share/ucarp/vip-up and vip-down:

```
  ----- up -----
  #!/bin/sh
  exec 2>/dev/null
  
  /sbin/ip address add "$2"/32 dev "$1"

  ------- down -------
  #!/bin/sh
  exec 2>/dev/null
  
  /sbin/ip address del "$2"/32 dev "$1"
```

Next step is to configure ucarp:

```
/usr/sbin/ucarp --interface=ens160 --pass=YourPassw00rd --srcip=10.0.215.26 --vhid=1 --addr=10.0.215.46 --shutdown --preempt --advskew=0 --upscript=/usr/share/ucarp/vip-up --downscript=/usr/share/ucarp/vip-down
```

You can change --pass to use file with --passfile. Srcip - ip of your machine, addr - virtual ip of your cluster.

I just tried this and everything was ok. I disabled ethernet on master node and  and switchover occurred after 2ms.

But there is one problem - UCARP is not a service, so you should create a unit for it.

```
nano /etc/systemd/system/ucarp.service
```

And fill it

```
[Unit]
#Unit description. You can see this message when use "service ucarp status"
Description=Start UCARP as service
# Start after this:
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
# Set type of service. Only oneshot works with exec lines with so much values. Look for Man page for instructions.
Type=oneshot
# Execute on start.
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/ucarp --interface=ens160 --pass=SuperPa$$w0rd --srcip=10.0.215.26 --vhid=1 --addr=10.0.215.46 --shutdown --preempt --advskew=0 --upscript=/usr/share/ucarp/vip-up --downscript=/usr/share/ucarp/vip-down -B
# Execute on stop.
KillMode=control-group
# Execute on reboot.
RemainAfterExit=yes


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And added to autostart

```
sudo systemctl enable ucarp
```

Comment: thx for the service file. There is a typo in "ERemainAfterExit=yes" FYI. The "E" is not valid ;-)

Comment: Thank you! Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The ucarp package includes integration for ifupdown but not for netplan.  It is on the list of packages that require updating, described at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ucarp/+bug/1718227.

If you are using the networkd backend, you can implement the hooks yourself locally as described in `networkd-dispatcher(8)`.  Otherwise, you always have the option of falling back to using ifupdown instead of netplan to configure the network interface that you need to run ucarp on.